# is it possible sharing to both facebook and twitter at same time in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

1. Sharing text and image to both facebook and twitter at same time in iOS?
2. List item

Comment: I think u try this work in last 4 days may be.

Comment: yes its possible... instagram do it...

Comment: yes , can you give me reference code for sharing ?

Comment: [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share) & [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios)